# sort numbers in one line

Tags: python, string, sorting

We have numbers in a string like this:

```
numbers = "1534423543"
```

We want to sort this and return:

```
"1,2,3,4,5"
```

(only unique numbers!)

How to do it in ONE line?

Comment: why is so important do it in one line?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

use `set()` to get unique items, then sort them using `sorted()` and finally join them using `",".join()`

```
In [109]: strs="1534423543"

In [110]: ",".join(sorted(set(strs)))
Out[110]: '1,2,3,4,5'
```

Comment: Do we need to use `sorted()` if string contains only numbers?

Comment: @Jaypal If you only want unique items then `set()` is enough, but if you want them in sorted order then use `sorted` as sets don't preserve order.

Comment: Thanks Ashwini. I was trying the solution in IDLE and noticed that if I used a string containing only numbers, `set()` always returned **unique** items in **sorted** order. So was wondering if we need to use `sorted()` only when dealing with `alphanum`.

Comment: @Jaypal That may be a co-incidence, but you shouldn't rely on sets for their ordering. In CPython they are implemented as hash tables.
`help(set)` --> **Build an *unordered* collection of unique elements.**

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thanks, I had a hunch that it was probably co-incidence. Appreciate your quick response. :)

Answer (score 5):

Ashwini has the answer that's on the tip of everyone's fingers - if you're up for an import, you could do...

```
from itertools import groupby; ','.join(k for k, g in groupby(sorted(nums)))
```

And that's *almost* one line :)

Comment: Why would you prefer this over the more simple `set` solution?

Comment: @mgilson I would definitely use the `set` solution, just thought I'd throw in an alternative (and thanks for edit)

Comment: semi-colons are cheating. Although I think an import shouldn't count